# Vaadin 14.1.17 - Get element selected in chart - Java

Tags: java, charts, vaadin, vaadin14

Hello i'm wondering how to retrieve the clicked element from a pie chart in Vaadin 14.1.17.

I'm using a classic pie with DataSeries and some values inside and i want to get the current selected item from a click listener

**DataSeries initialization**

```
DataSeries ds = new DataSeries();

for (AssetClassModel a : p.getAssetClasses()) {
    ds.add(new DataSeriesItem(a.getDesc(), a.getPerc()));
}
conf.setSeries(ds);
```

I've tried reading the `selected` field inside `DataSeriesItem` but it's always `false`

**Click Listener**

```
chart.addSeriesClickListener(
        e -> {
            List<DataSeriesItem> items = ((DataSeries) e.getSeries()).getData();

            for (DataSeriesItem item : items) {
                System.out.println(item.getName() + " selected: " + item.isSelected());
            }

        }
);
```

**Output**

```
value1 selected: false
value2 selected: false
value4 selected: false
```

Do you have any idea on how to manage this?

Thanks
Davide

Answer (score 0):

*This is more of a workaround, but seems to work :)*

The `SeriesClickEvent` has a `getMouseDetails().getyValue()` method. The returned value matches with the `y` value of an item. (It's the second constructor parameter of a `DataSeriesItem`)

```java
chart.addSeriesClickListener(event->{
     series.getData().forEach( item->{
          if(event.getMouseDetails().getyValue()== ((DataSeriesItem)item).getY().doubleValue()){
              System.out.println("SELECTED : " +  ((DataSeriesItem)item).getName());
           }
     });
});
```

The `isSelected()` method seems to rely on the `selected` property set implicitly using `item.setSelected(true);`. This was confusing for me as well, so it's either a bug or a non documented behaviour.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer; unfortunately it seems that it not works very well since in my case i've two items with the same Y value.

Any idea?